# Force Reload a Page with Javascript (No Button)

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I'm working on a site, and when an individual visits a certain page, I need the page to refresh.

I tried using location.reload() as well as the timeout function, but the page kept reloading. I just need to impose a limitation on the function to have one relaod.

Comment: Could you say _why_ this is necessary?

Comment: Is that one reload forever?,.   `localeStorage` will persist forever, `sessionStorage` will persist until page is closed.   But if you want this page referesh to happen again if you visit the same page you would be better with History state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a page to perform a task on load, but also *know* whether or not it *should* perform that task based on a *previous* load, then what you're taking about is persisting information outside of the page.

`localStorage` is a common approach.  For example, consider the following:

```
const hasReloaded = localStorage.getItem('hasReloaded') || false;
if (!hasReloaded) {
  localStorage.setItem('hasReloaded', 'true');
  location.reload();
}
```

The first thing the code does is look for a value in `localStorage`.  If the value doesn't exist, it defaults to `false`.  So when `hasReloaded` is `false`, the `if` block executes.  Within that block, write a value to `localStorage` and reload.

The next time the page loads, when it checks the value again it finds it and the `if` block doesn't execute.